# React hooks setState not updating immediately

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to validate field when I click on submit button. This is how I defined my state.

```
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    email: "",
    password: "",
    emailErrorMessage: "",
    passwordErrorMessage: "",
    errorMessage: "",
    emailError: false,
    passwordError: false,
    rememberMe: false,
  });
```

In submit method, this is how I am validating it.

```
if (values.email.length <= 0) {

  setValues({
    ...values,
    emailError: true,
    emailErrorMessage: "Email field must not be empty"
  })
};

if (values.password.length <= 0) {
  setValues({ ...values, passwordError: true, passwordErrorMessage: "Password field must not be empty" });
}
```

For somehow it is only showing me error for password field. Although it is going through both the if conditions. Not sure how exactly I can Fix it.

Expected:- it should show error for both email and password.

Comment: how are you calling the submit method?

Comment: <Button
          type="submit"
          fullWidth
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          onClick={handleSubmit}
        >

Comment: With onclick property of button

Comment: state updates are async,

Comment: any idea how we can make it synchronous or any other way to solve this?

Comment: basically the operations are happening so quickly that you can't see the change. I am sure if you remove the password checking block then you will see the error for email also

Comment: Thanks @ParnabSanyal. I solved it with below answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Problem 1:** The state update is an asynchronous process, so, in your case, you're updating the state for the first time by spreading the current state, then you're updating it for the second time, by spreading also the current state (not updated yet). As a result, the last state successfully updated (it's a gamble actually, with more luck for the second update) will be the actual nextState, that's why you encounter the password being updated only

**Problem 2:** Every state update triggers a re-render. You're updating the state twice (even though it's done wrong, but it's a fact), when you could do it just once (to have just one re-render).

A solution to solve both problems will be:

```
const newValues = {...values};

if (values.email.length <= 0) {
  newValues.emailError = true;
  newValues.emailErrorMessage = "Email field must not be empty";
};

if (values.password.length <= 0) {
  newValues.passwordError = true;
  newValues.passwordErrorMessage = "Password field must not be empty";
}

setValues(newValues);
```

Comment: So basically the variable is being overwritten

Comment: The `values` is not overwritten. There's a new constant `newValues`, which is a copy of `values`. A property value update of `newValues` doesn't affect `values`, so the state is immutable.

Comment: Thanks, @Garry for the update on my answer. It's actually late for me and I'm tired :D And I just copy pasted some parts of the code. P.S. I'll better go to sleep. Happy coding!

Comment: @RaduNemerenco your welcome and thanks to you for helping this. I am trying to make it performance optimized. So it won't rerender again and again. Actually your answer also helped me to make rerender when needed.

Comment: Shouldn't `values.emailError`, etc.. be `newValues.emailError` ? Like [this](https://codepen.io/oze4/pen/yWmqyZ?editors=1010) or like [this](https://codepen.io/oze4/pen/LowBpZ?editors=1010) ***EDIT*** nevermind, looks like you fixed it...

Comment: Yes @Matt Oestreich, it should. It was a copy-paste mistake from my side. Garry's got the point and requested to update my answer, which is the same solution as in your second option. Just a note on your first option: spread operator is nice, but there's no point of creating a new object for every update. As a comparison, in the first example of yours you're creating 3 new objects. In the second update, you're creating just one new object. This is a simple/trivial update, but you might get big performance issues in a bigger application if you're following the same path.

Comment: @RaduNemerenco I agree - thanks for the input - I would go with the second example I provided if I were writing this.. Just supplied that as another example.. but it makes me wonder, does that actually create 3 new objects? It doesn't just copy over the props since there is no new assignment?

Answer (score -3):

@RaduNemerenco has a good answer but you can just add another if statement that checks for both conditions

```
if (values.email.length <= 0) {

  setValues({
    ...values,
    emailError: true,
    emailErrorMessage: "Email field must not be empty"
  })
};

if (values.password.length <= 0) {
  setValues({ ...values, passwordError: true, passwordErrorMessage: "Password field must not be empty" });
}

if (values.email.length <= 0 && values.password.length <= 0) {

  setValues({
    ...values,
    emailError: true,
    emailErrorMessage: "Email field must not be empty",
    passwordError: true,
    passwordErrorMessage: "Password field must not be empty"
  })
};
```

Comment: Why we need 3rd condition if above two conditions are same? It will be passing through both the if conditions so 3rd condition is unnecessary.

Comment: it not correct in that way. I think you misunderstood the problem