# ReactJS How to synchronize my text input and button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a simple search bar. The input label read a string and once the content is changed the state inputString is updated. Once the user click the 'search' button, we split the 'inputString' and assign the string[] to state 'keywords', then such an array will be used to send a request.

I still have limited knowledge of asynchronous issues in JS. So I'd like to know how can I make sure every time I click the button, I split the newest inputString? (console.log tells me I don't, but is that another asynchronous issue?)

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function Search(){
    const [inputString, setInputString] = useState('');
    const [keywords, setKeywords] = useState([]);

    function sendSearchKeywords(){
        const InputStringRemovedSpace = inputString.replace(/ +(?= )/g,'');
        setKeywords(InputStringRemovedSpace.split(' '));
        console.log(inputString);
        //do something about request here
        console.log(keywords);
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <input type='text' placeholder="enter your keywords" onChange={(e)=>{
                    setInputString(e.target.value);
                }}/>
                <button onClick={()=>{
                    sendSearchKeywords();
                }}>Search</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React hooks setState not updating immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56510211/react-hooks-setstate-not-updating-immediately)

Answer (score 2):

**React `setState is not asynchronous` but we can use `useEffect` hook.**

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function Search(){
    const [inputString, setInputString] = useState('');
    const [keywords, setKeywords] = useState([]);

    React.useEffect(() => {
      console.log(inputString);
      //do something about request here 
      console.log(keywords);
    }, [keywords]);

    function sendSearchKeywords(){
        const InputStringRemovedSpace = inputString.replace(/ +(?= )/g,'');
        setKeywords(InputStringRemovedSpace.split(' '));
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <input type='text' placeholder="enter your keywords" onChange={(e)=>                                                
                {
                    setInputString(e.target.value);
                }}/>
                <button onClick={()=>{
                    sendSearchKeywords();
                }}>Search</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```